# Как запустить загрузку файла в отдельном потоке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

При event == 'Download', интерфейс зависает до окончания загрузки файла. А нужно возвращение в основной цикл.

```
import youtube_dl
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from multiprocessing import Process

key_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio']
format_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio/best']

layout = [[sg.Input('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHNzOHi8sJs&' , key='Link_youtube' , size=(50 , 1)),
           sg.InputOptionMenu(key_list , size=(20 , 1), key='key_set')] ,
          [sg.Button('Download')]]
window = sg.Window('' , layout)



def start_download():
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([values['Link_youtube']])

def start():
    p = Process(target=start_download())
    p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:  # Event Loop App
        event , values = window.Read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Download':
            start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше пользоваться потоками https://python-scripts.com/threading:

```
from threading import Thread
import youtube_dl
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from multiprocessing import Process

key_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio']
format_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio/best']

layout = [[sg.Input('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHNzOHi8sJs&', key='Link_youtube', size=(50, 1)),
           sg.InputOptionMenu(key_list, size=(20, 1), key='key_set')],
          [sg.Button('Download')]]
window = sg.Window('', layout)


def start_download():
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([values['Link_youtube']])


class Download(Thread):
    def run(self):
        start_download()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:  # Event Loop App
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Download':
            t = Download()
            t.start()
```

Comment: Думаю, лучше тут не создавать свой класс потока: `t = Download()` -> `t = Thread(target=start_download)`

Comment: `"Лучше пользоваться потоками"` - аргументируйте, почему лучше

Comment: @insolor процесс это уже отдельная программа, для запуска которой нужно выделять соответствующие ресурсы, поток же использует ресурсы текущего процесса

Answer (score 3):

Ты передавал не функцию, а её результат:
вот так работать будет:

```
import youtube_dl
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from multiprocessing import Process

key_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio']
format_list = ['bestvideo+bestaudio/best']

layout = [[sg.Input('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHNzOHi8sJs&' , key='Link_youtube' , size=(50 , 1)),
           sg.InputOptionMenu(key_list , size=(20 , 1), key='key_set')] ,
          [sg.Button('Download')]]
window = sg.Window('' , layout)



def start_download():
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([values['Link_youtube']])

def start():
    p = Process(target=start_download) #ошибка была тут
    p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:  # Event Loop App
        event , values = window.Read()
        if event is None or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Download':
            start()
```